# How to remove the border of the CKEditor 5 text field?

Tags: css, ckeditor, textarea, border, ckeditor5

Please help me solve a seemingly simple question. I have not found a solution to this problem. I tried using CSS and just changing the parameters - it doesn't work. I just need to remove or hide the border of the CKEditor 5 text box. How can I do this?

Thanks!

[image]

```
<textarea id="editor"><p>Text...</p></textarea>

ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor'), {
        } )
        .then( editor => {
            const toolbarElement = editor.ui.view.toolbar.element;                
            toolbarElement.style.display = 'none';
            editor.enableReadOnlyMode( 'my-feature-id' );
        } )
        .catch( err => {
            console.error( err.stack );
        } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it when console log **editor.ui.view**

```
ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor'), {
        } )
        .then( editor => {
            const editableElement = editor.ui.view.editable.element;
            editableElement.style.border = 'none';
        } )
        .catch( err => {
            console.error( err.stack );
        } );
```

Answer (score 1):

In angular by using ng-deep you can remove the border, please refer the below code

```
:: ng-deep .ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable:not(.ck-focused){

    border: hidden
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).